# Storing a word in reserved memory

Tags: assembly, memory, mips, .data

I am coding in MIPS Assembly language and reserved 12 byts in .data.

```
.data 
bool: .space 12 #12 byts to be able to save 3 words
other_data: .asciiz "Part of some other data I saved"

.text
...
li $a1, 4
la $a0, guess #address to read sting in
li $v0, 8 #read string
syscall
...
```

The string is recorded into 1 byte from the address of $a0 but I want to seperate each character into a seperate byte

Comment: Have you tried using a label name that isn't a C++ type name?  `bool` might be a reserved word in whatever assembler you're using.  (Check the machine code and disassembly to see what happened.)  That should work for a label name like `foo` or `my_bool` with most assemblers, that will treat it as a pseudo-instruction and expand it to `lui` / `sw` using `$at` for the high half of the 32-bit address.  (BTW, it's unusual to use 4 bytes for a `bool`; you only need one if it's always 0 or 1.)

Comment: You did not show but I expect `$a0` to contain an address. You likely want to copy the letters to `bool` so you will need a loop.

Comment: $a0 contains the result of 

li $v0, 8 #read string
 syscall
I will try with a loop, thank you

Comment: The read string syscall already expects a pointer to the buffer. `$a0` is not an output, it's an input. Along with `$a1` for the size.

Comment: That instruction `sw $a0, label` is a pseudo instruction, meaning that MIPS has no corresponding machine code instruction.  Your assembler will change that into some other code sequence, such as `lui`/`ori`/`sw` using `$1`, or perhaps `sw $a0,offset($gp)`.  You should observe the machine code instructions and debug as such.

Comment: See the docs: https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html .  That syscall doesn't allocate new memory or pack the characters into a 4-byte register, it's like C `fread` or actually `fgets`, it takes a pointer and length as inputs.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets  .  If it returned a value, it would return in `$v0`.  (But it doesn't, so it annoyingly doesn't tell you how many bytes were read.  Real OSes have system calls that do return the length for I/O operations, or error status on failure.)